# How do I kill "SQL Developer" that seem to be in deadlock using ps aux and kill -9?

Tags: macos, oracle

I have SQL Developer from Oracle installed. It seems to be frozen at the moment and I can't force quit it.

I can't open it because of this and hence can't use it too

I don't want to shut down my Mac every time so I want to kill it using `kill -9` but I don't know its name nor pid so I'm clueless.

How do I kill it?

Answer (score 1):

If you can't find it by running `ps aux` or `pgrep -i developer` you can run Activity Monitor to get the PID of the process (and also to kill it directly).

Comment: I can't see the SQL Developer process in Activity Monitor when this situation happen. I'm guessing its associated service are still half alive even though the main application seems to have been killed and we need to kill the associated service. But I don't know how to tell which one to kill

Answer (score 0):

I have also encountered this issue a number of times. No matter what I do it is impossible to stop the task from the Mac force quit dialog (CMD-OPT-ESC). I have also tried to identify the task using `pgrep` and `ps aux`. It almost looks like it is a phantom process in Finder.

Even though I am not able to get rid of this process, I am able to start a new process with Terminal `/Applications/SQLDeveloper.app/Contents/MacOS/sqldeveloper.sh`

I hope this helps